# Jquery keep class after ajax calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

First some important info. I can't change anything in the calls, code, functions etc that are used. So bottomline is that I have to use a workaround.

Ok I have a form with some fields and a dropdown. 
When loading that form I hide a specific field with some jquery. That field isw hidden when the value matches some value in an array. The problem i'm facing is that when we use the `dropdown` there's an json call being made to an external service (for countries) and then the form is being updated.

Since I can't get to the code that updates the form after a succesfull json call I need to find something to check if everything is done loading and if so hide my specific field again.

To make things clear:

```
<div class="checkout-shipment-methods hidden">
    <input id="EuPack" name="shipment_method" value="EuPack" type="radio">
    <label for="EuPack">Delivered at home</label>
 </div>
 <div class="checkout-shipment-methods">
    <input id="Pack" name="shipment_method" value="Pack" type="radio">
    <label for="Pack">Delivered at work</label>
 </div>      
<select id="billing_address-country" name="billing_address[country]">
   <option value="be" selected="selected">België</option>
   <option value="dk">Denemarken</option>
   <option value="de">Duitsland</option>
</select>
```

`input` is hidden now. When I change `select` the form is updated and the class `hidden` is removed.

If I change the `select` then there are 2 calls made -> 
[image]

So I thought to check if those calls are made and if so add that class `hidden` again.

Like so:

```
    $(function(){

      var a = [ 'FP32PE4','FP32LE4' ];
      var b = [ 'FP32PE1','FP32PE4' ];

          $.each( a, function( key, value ) {
            var index = $.inArray( value, b );
            if( index != -1 ) {

              var $id =  $('.checkout-shipment-methods:first-of-type');
              $id.addClass('hidden');
              localStorage.setItem("selectedolditem", $id);

                  $.ajax({
                    url: "url-to-link-in-image/nl/checkout/onestep/details/",
                    beforeSend: function( xhr ) {
                        xhr.overrideMimeType( "text/plain; charset=x-user-defined" );
                    }
                  }).
                  then(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
                    console.log('success');
                       var selectedolditem = localStorage.getItem('selectedolditem');
                       if (selectedolditem != null) {
                         $('.checkout-shipment-methods:first-of-type').addClass("hidden");
                        }   

                      }, 
                      function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
                         console.log('fail')

                  });
            }
        });
      });
```

Is that even possible?

Comment: "Is that even possible?". Well, you wrote it...did you try it? Did it work?

Comment: did I understand you ok,, you need a way to alter some elements css class,, remove `hidden` from elements after service call has been made?

Comment: @ADyson: Oow haha.... Yes offcourse I tried. Above code hides the element on page load. However after changing the select it removes the class `hidden`

Comment: @oserk: See my comment above. So when I load the page the first time it adds class `hidden`. But when changijng the select the form removes that class again

Comment: see my answer @Meules,, hope that helps ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ok,, so you can capture simply the `ajaxComplete` event,, that triggers everytime ajax is fired.. do something like this:

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function( event, xhr, settings ) {
  if ( settings.url.indexOf( "nl/service/regions/" ) != '-1' ) {
     $('.checkout-shipment-methods:first-of-type').removeClass("hidden");
  }
});
```

and that should work,, little expl:

- we are watching every ajax call from webpage
- if ajax call is to address like: /regions ..
- if call is captured, simply call removeClass on target elemeent

cheers, k